# Un doble-sentido en "Radio Tertulia"

Tags: traducción, diferencias-regionales, argentina, humor

En la obra *Radio Tertulia* de **Les Luthiers**, los conductores de un programa de radio maltraducen el inglés al español con consequencias graciosas.   [En una parte (3:02)](http://youtu.be/MW9GxhBZVMQ), dicen lo siguiente:

> **Jorge Maronna:** And the manager said...
>   **Daniel Rabinovich:** El manager tenía sed.
>   **Jorge Maronna:** Come on. Trust me!

Entonces, parece que los conductores se espantaron porque "Come on. Trust me!" es algo tan escandaloso que ni siquiera querían traducir.  La neta es que no entiendo dónde está el chiste en esto.

Por la risa de la audiencia, parece que hay algo que no entiendo en la interpretación de los sonidos de "Come on. Trust me!" de inglés al español.

- ¿Qué es lo que me escapa aquí?
- ¿Alguien me puede explicar el chiste?
- ¿Será un doble sentido?
- ¿O será algo más?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El usuario `Jamespianista` también lo pregunta. De la respuesta de `beto2768`:

> Pasa que en Argentina una forma vulgar de referirse al trasero o a las nalgas es "traste" De allí "trust" (pronunciado como "trast") suena a "traste", o sea, nalga, cola, trasero.

Busca antes en los comentarios del vídeo si alguien ha tenido la misma duda que tú.

Comment: Lo primero que me viene a la mente cuando escucho `Come on` es jamón. Pero hay que tener mucha imaginación para pasar de 'Come on, trust me' a 'Jamón traste a mí' o "Méteme un jamón por el traste"